# Change array in to object in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my array format

```
let array = [
  0: { 
        key:"name",
        value: "John" 
     },
  1: {
        key:"age", 
        value:25
     },
  2: { 
        key:"job", 
        value:"software engineer" 
     },...
];
```

Change this array to object in given below format

```
{ 
  name: "John",
  age: 27, 
  job: "software engineer" 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using [**`forEach`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) on the array.

Give this a try:

```js
const array = [{
  key: "name",
  value: "John"
}, {
  key: "age",
  value: 25
}, {
  key: "job",
  value: "software engineer"
}];

const expected = {};
array.forEach(item => expected[item.key] = item.value);

console.log(expected);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to do this:

```js
let array = [
     { 
        key:"name",
        value: "John" 
     },
     {
        key:"age", 
        value:25
     },
     { 
        key:"job", 
        value:"software engineer" 
     }
];

let result = array.reduce((a,b) => {
  a[b.key] = b.value;
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is to loop over the array using `forEach, for loop, while loop etc`and push the values in a new object.

Also make sure that your array syntax is correct because the way you have mentioned it in the question is incorrect.

```js
const data = [{ key:"name", value: "John" },{ key:"age", value:25 },{ key:"job", value:"software engineer" } ];
const res = {};
data.forEach(item => { res[item.key] = item.value});
console.log(res);
```